# Eigenvectors of $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is an eigenvector of $A^n$ the same as an eigenvector of $A$? I think it should be but I am just confirming. I know the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are the eigenvalues of $A $ raised to the $n$th power.

Answer (score 2):

An eigenvector $v$ for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ will be an eigenvector for $A^2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$, but $A^2$ could have additional eigenvectors (or eigenvalues for that matter).

Consider for instance $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ or $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Now, why would $A^n$ have additional Eigen vectors? I mean Eigen vectors are those which are not transformed in direction but only in magnitude.

Comment: @jnyan A concrete example is the matrix that rotates all vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ by some angle that is a rational multiple of $2\pi$, say by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You can see that this matrix cannot preserve the direction of any nonzero vector in $\Bbb R^2$, but applying this matrix four times is just the identity matrix, which keeps all vectors unchanged.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Or just think about the examples I included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Observe if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then
\begin{align}
A^2v= A(Av)= A(\lambda v) = \lambda Av = \lambda^2 v.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Goes well with my geometric interpretation of Eigen vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue of $\lambda$. Then,
$$A^2x =A(Ax) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda \cdot Ax = \lambda \cdot \lambda x = \lambda^2 x$$
and hence $x$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue of $\lambda^2$.

It's not too difficult to see that you can extend this idea to higher powers of $A$ (you can use induction to show this rigorously).